# ASP.NET - Update DataSet Table Adapter to match Database Data Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Have been learning ASP.NET (using C#) over the past few days.

I have made everything as I need it, now realised one of my datatypes in the database needs to change from an `int` to a `bigint`. I managed to change that fine in all the tables, but my queries that call Table Adapters still are looking for an `int` not a `long / bigint`.

Could someone tell me how to update the datatypes in a dataset / table adapter please to match the database schema.

(Not sure if it makes much difference but I am using Visual Studio 2010)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **[DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)** of the `DataTable`'s `DataColumn` in your `DataSet` to **Int64**.

Comment: Could you tell me how please?

Comment: On the designer, select the column you need to change its datatype, then from the properties window change the datatype property to int64.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you created the dataadapters and the datasets.
If you did it using the wizard in Visual Studio, you can change the dataadapter by right-clicking it and select `Configure Data Adapter`. To recreate the datasets, right-click the dataadapter and select `Generate DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the Generate DataSet seems like something I need. I can't find the option though. I am looking at my DataSet.xsd and need to recreate one of my tableadapters. Where do I find these options

Comment: If you dragged the DataAdapter onto a form or component, you can right-click it. If you created the DataAdapter in code, you probably need to change the Select, Insert, Update, Delete commands manually. Look for SqlParameter in your code, and make sure it is using the right type. The DataSet can be changed manually by either opening it in the designer or in an xml editor.